# Apply "one-column function" to whole data frame

Tags: r, function

Here is a sample data frame `df` and a vector `s`:

```
x1 <- c(12:4, 5:8, NA, NA)
x2 <- c(15:8, 9:15)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
s <- c(9,8)
```

Now I want to delete the values in each column before the row numbers given in `s` which works with

`df1 <- df[s[1]:nrow(df[1]), 1]`

for a single column. But I can't get it to work for the whole data frame.
I've tried the following (and various other functions):

```
rec  <- function(x){df[s[x]:nrow(df[x]), x]}
df1 <- lapply(df, rec)
```

But I'm always getting errors like that:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, s[x]:nrow(df[x]), x) : undefined columns selected
```

Don't know where the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: So do you want to delete the first 9 rows in column 1 and the first 8 in column 2? If so do you want NA in column 1 row 1 (previously row 8). Or do you just want to eliminate the first 9 rows in all columns?

Comment: You provide the whole `data.frame` as x in the `lapply`-call, instead of the column number. Try: `lapply(1:ncol(df), rec)`, but this returns a list with the separate vectors of different lenght, so it is not possible to put those in one `data.frame`. It might be helpful to show your desired output.

Comment: @Rob This is exactly what I need, thanks. I don't really care if `df` is a list or data frame. But I don't completely understand where the difference is between `(1:ncol(df), rec)` and `(df, rec)`.

Comment: Glad to help. With `1:ncol(df)`, which would in this case be `1:2`, you give the column numbers that are used to subset `df` in your function. Filling in the whole data.frame there doesn't work, since R expects only the numbers of the rows and columns: `[rownumbers,columnnumbers]`. Also see ?``[`` The answers below also give you the same result and might provide you some more insight.

Answer (score 3):

Try `mapply`. In general I opt for it when it comes to invoke the same function against a list (the column in df) using different parameters for each item in the list:

```
> mapply(`[`, df, lapply(s, `:`, nrow(df)))
$x1
[1]  4  5  6  7  8 NA NA

$x2
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

the above applies the `[` operator against each column (taken as atomic vector) and use as argument each item inside

```
> lapply(s, `:`, nrow(df))
[[1]]
[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

so, the first would be `df$x1[9:15]`, the second `df$x2[8:15]`. Hope it is what you want.

EDIT: `sapply` changed to `lapply` as discussed with Hadley in comments.

EDIT2: some timings to compare different approaches as suggested in comments below

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10000),
                  x2 = rnorm(10000))


method1 <- function(data, limits)
  mapply(`[`, data, lapply(limits, `:`, nrow(data)))

method2 <- function(data, limits)
  mapply(function(x, i) x[-(1:(i-1))], data, limits)


> identical(method1(df1, s),method2(df1, s))
[1] TRUE
> 
> microbenchmark(method1(df1, s),method2(df1, s))
Unit: microseconds
            expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 method1(df1, s) 239.250 250.1550 258.6525 273.0855  423.658   100
 method2(df1, s) 548.734 568.4585 584.3340 599.4075 1664.164   100
```

Comment: `lapply` would be more appropriate than `sapply` here: you're not simplifying the output.

Comment: @hadley good point...  it's a waste of time and not only actually! if all elements of `s` are the same it'll create a matrix and `mapply` won't work as expected... thanks.

Comment: You could get rid of the sapply altogether by using `function(i) df[-(1:i), ]`

Comment: @hadley true, but it'll be 2x slower. microbenchmark()ed with 10k row data frames. Not using anonymous function is more efficient probably. Do they get "compiled" every time `mapply` call them? Well.. even if it were there are only 2 column to loop through so I guess it's not eventually impacting in case.

Comment: Interesting! But no compilation going on. More likely to be that negative indexing is slow.

Comment: Might also want to use `Map` instead of `mapply` to avoid simplification of output.

Answer (score 0):

`tail(x,n)` with negative `n` returns all elements of x without the first `n` ones.

```
mapply(function(a,b) tail(a, -b), df, s)
lapply(1:2, function(x) tail(df[,x], -s[x]))
```

EDIT(Michele): Since you want it to return a subset including the rows defined by `s` you'll need to increase `b` by one.

```
mapply(function(a,b) tail(a, -b+1), df, s)
```

Comment: Won't this return a `list`? Although it is not completely clear, it seems that the OP wants a `data.frame` output. That said, the use of `tail()` is clever.

Comment: @JohnPaul if wants a `data.frame`, but I doubt it, he would need to fill the gaps, because the output is different length vectors. The above was also slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
df$new<-as.numeric(rownames(df))
s<-as.list(s)
n<-as.list(names(df)[-3])
k<-Map(function(x,y)df[df$new>=x,y],s,n)
[[1]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8 NA NA

[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

If you want the dataframe:

```
data.frame(t(do.call(rbind,kk)))



 X1 X2
1  4  8
2  5  9
3  6 10
4  7 11
5  8 12
6 NA 13
7 NA 14
8  4 15
```

Note: R does recycling here since the number of elements in the X1 and X2 is not the same